# Validate the checkbox limit to 5

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>HTML Checkbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>



    enter code here
    <h2> Pick your most favorite fruits: </h2>


     <form name="fruitcheckbox" action="fruits.php" method="POST">


       <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="orange"> Orange
       <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple"> Apple
       <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit"> Grapefruit
       <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="banana"> Banana
       <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="watermelon"> Watermelon
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btnsave">
     </form>
```

Anyone can give me an idea how to validate this checkobox array.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))

{   $fruit = $_POST['fruit'];
    $values = array();
     foreach($chkbox as $selection )
     {     if(in_array($selection, $fruit))
             { $values[ $selection ] = 1;  }
         else
             { $values[ $selection ] = 0;  }
          }
```

this is part of my code. I want to limit the checked checkbox to 5. Thanks. I need it badly :|

Comment: it will return an array of values, just use `count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can limit in javascript itself. So you can limit user in client side no need to go server side. It will limit you for 4 items. You can change the number in the script to increase the value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function validateitem(){
             var items = document.forms['fruitcheckbox'];
                var inc = 0;
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    if (items[i].checked) {
                        inc++;
                    }
                }
                if(inc == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("limitmsg").innerHTML = 'Select atleast 1 item.';
                    return false;
                } else if(inc>4){
                    document.getElementById("limitmsg").innerHTML = 'You can select only 4 items.';
                    return false;
                }
                }
         </script>
    <h2>Pick your most favorite fruits:</h2>


    <form name="fruitcheckbox" action="fruits.php" method="POST"
        onsubmit="return validateitem();">


        <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="orange"> Orange <input
            type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple"> Apple <input
            type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit"> Grapefruit <input
            type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="banana"> Banana <input
            type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="watermelon"> Watermelon <br> <span
            style="color: red" id="limitmsg"></span><input type="submit"
            value="Save" name="btnsave">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
if (isset($_POST['btnsave'])) {

$fruits = $_POST['fruit'];

$count = count($fruits);

if ($count > 5) {

// Error; Only 5 checks allowed

} else {

// Save the data

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit fields with brackets like in your example. name="fruit[]" it will be an array when it is received in the backend in php.
You could then just use this:

```
if(isset($_POST['fruit']) && count($_POST['fruit']) > 5) {
    // add your error message
} else {
    // Everything is fine as long as you dont have to select atleast one of them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is not wrong you have more then 5 checkboxes and you want user to restrict to check only 5 checkboxes.

If this is the case then below code might help you.

```
$("input[name='fruit[]']").change(function(e) {
      if($('input[name="fruit[]"]:checked').length==5) {
          $("input[name='fruit[]']:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
      } else {
          $("input[name='fruit[]']:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", false);
      }
 });
```

Above code will allow you to check only 5 check boxes, whenever user check the 5th checkbox it will disable the remaining unchecked checkboxes. whenever user uncheck any of the 5 checkboxes then it will enable all the checkboxes.